# Integrating $\sin^3(x)/(2+\cos(x))$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I could use some help solving the following integral:

$$\int \frac{\sin^3(x)}{2+\cos(x)} dx$$

---

So far I tried using the equality:
$$\sin^3(x) = \frac{3}{4} \sin(x) - \frac{1}{4}\sin(3x)$$

which wasn't useful, then I tried using substitution when
$$t=2+\cos(x)$$

wasn't much help either, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Write $\sin^3x=\sin x(1-\cos^2x)$

and set $2+\cos x=y\iff\cos x=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{2+\cos x} = -\left(\frac{d}{dx}\cos x\right)\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{2+\cos x}$$
hence you just need to integrate:
$$\frac{1-z^2}{2+z} = 2-z-\frac{5}{2+z},$$
not a difficult task.